# Parity of all possible sums

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, contest-math

> The numbers $1, 2, 3, \dots, 1024$ are written on a blackboard. They are divided into pairs. Then each pair is wiped off the board and non-negative difference of its numbers is written on the board instead. $512$ numbers obtained in this way are divided into pairs and so on. One number remains on the blackboard after ten such operations. Determine all its possible values.

In [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1676931p10683748) soution (1st one), how is it clear that all possible values must have same parity ?

I think I am missing something obvious, pls someone help...

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any integer and it's negative is of same parity.  $$a \equiv -a \pmod 2$$

We see $$\pm a_1 \pm a_2 \pm a_3 \ldots \pm a_n \equiv a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \ldots a_n \pmod 2$$

Any combination of addition, subtraction results in same parity as all additions.

Comment: but its not true that any final number is some combination of addition, subtraction of original numbers ?

Comment: for ex - if we have set $(1,2,3,4)$ and partition as $P=(1,4),(2,3)$ then we have $S_1=(3,1)$ implies $S_2=2$ ,i still dont understand pls explain a bit more ...

Comment: There are $2^{1024}$ combinations of $\pm$. Our sums result from roughly 512 +'s and 512 -'s. Because at each step, we taking positive difference, $|a_i-a_j|$.

Comment: For $(1,2,3,4)$, $S_2=-1+2-3+4$. Two $+$, two $-$.

Comment: @Ishan In your example, $2=3-1=(4-1)-(3-2)=-1+2-3+4$.